# jquery sessionStorage boolean value unexpectedly changed to string

Tags: jquery, session-storage

```
sessionStorage.setItem("loadCase", false);

if (sessionStorage.getItem("loadCase")){
alert("Hello!")
} else {
alert("Bye")
}
```

I expect "Bye" but get "Hello!"

However, when I changed the condition, it works

```
sessionStorage.setItem("loadCase", false);

if (sessionStorage.getItem("loadCase")=="true"){
alert("Hello!")
} else {
alert("Bye")
}
```

Can I know why when I set an item as Boolean but return as string from sessionStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally SessionStorage, treat data as an string, It doesn't matter what kind of data/type you saved in it, It's better if you make use of JSON `parse` and `stringify` method to `serialize` and `deserialize` the data,

Please have a look below

```
var value = sessionStorage.getItem("loadCase");
console.log(JSON.parse(value) === true); // true
```